# How to zoom and focus Android camera using audio jack?

Tags: android, zooming, android-camera2, autofocus, shutter

[image: Audio Jack]
[image: Focus control camera]

I want to control zoom or focus of my Android phone's camera using audio jack. It is common to use audio jack to take picture or probably we may call it as shutter. It is done by connecting the mic port and the ground as shown in the picture 2 (I took it from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gfb5IDisUkY). It is not Android, but probably the same idea is possible with Android). Is it possible to do zoom or focus using the audio jack? Say, like we manipulate or rearrange it something like explained in picture 1? Picture 1 taken from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bvDvq_pmWY).

Comment: Are you writing your own camera app?

Comment: If it is not possible by just connect the audio jack terminal, then I have to write the app. But still I prefer if without wring app.

Comment: I prefer like using potentiometer connected to the ground and either to the right, left, and the mic port to control the zoom, if it is possible without writing any app.

Comment: There are hundreds of camera apps, both pre-installed and user-installed. Have you contacted the developers of any of them to see if they expose APIs to allow third-party apps like yours to control the features that you want?

Comment: Yes, of course, there are many. But I just want to make a simple one, just like a selfie stick without too many complications, if it is possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare, btw, is it possible to do programming with C/C++? I saw so far, Android Studio is using Java. I have no experience with Java.

Answer (score 0):

The Android [specification](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/jack-headset-spec) for the audio Jack, this gives you the input/key events that can be generated by the audio jack. Your camera application should listen for these events and do the appropriate action.

How to create hardware to generate the events is [here](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec)

Comment: Let me study your links.

Comment: After I searched carefully in the links you provided, sadly no pertaining camera there. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes you missed something, the camera is just an App, this is how the system converts the audio jack input in to normal key presses, it is up to each App to decided how it wants to responded to the "volume up, volume down, etc" key presses. You should check the documentation of your camera App to see how it responds to these normal key presses, as there are many different camera Apps depending of make and model of phone and or what extra Apps you have install. If you are writing your own camera App these are the normal key press it should respond to.

Comment: "You should check the documentation of your camera App to see how it responds to these normal key presses, as there are many different camera Apps depending of make and model of phone". There is no documentation for it, I just checked the manual book. But however, I check the phone itself, I found that only the volume button is working related to camera. Both Vol Up and Vol Down are have the same function, that is to take picture. The power button is not working related to camera. It is to power of the display  off when the camera is being ON/active.

Comment: Therefore you need to write your own Camera App that responds differently to the buttons.